# Django: Is this a viable alternative method for including CSRF tokens in template forms?

Tags: python, django, security, csrf

I usually add CSRF tokens to forms in templates in the format specified by the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/csrf/#how-to-use-it):

```
<form action="" method="post">{{ csrf_token }}
... 
</form>
```

However, I've seen snippets of code where an author includes a CSRF token as follows:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <div style="display:none">
        <input type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token }}" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken">
    </div>
...
</form>
```

Is there any benefit of using the latter instead of the former?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: later one is completely same as the former one. Later one I have used it when I needed to give some explicit AJAX requests from java script with some dynamic inputs. Other than that their is no other benifit.

Answer (score 0):

They both produce the same results.  The official documentation located [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/) has examples of using the `csrf_token` outside of the `form` tag.  The difference in behavior is relative to where the `csrf_token` variable is placed - if outside of the `form` tags it knows to build the form for you - if placed inside the `form` tags it knows to just grab the actual value however the end result is the same.

One of the reasons why there are multiple ways to produce the same result is to add support for 3rd-party templates.  I think in terms of performance you won't see much difference (although the variant of using the `csrf_token` inside the tags might return faster because Django won't have to dynamically generate an entire form for you since you have already built it).